# How to write a custom comparator for a QList of pointers?

Tags: c++, qt, operator-overloading

I have a `QList<MyPoint*> l` where `MyPoint` is a user-defiend class type where I'd like to do:

```
 QList<MyPoint*> l;
 MyPoint *a = new MyPoint(2, 4);
 MyPoint *b = new MyPoint(4, 8);
 MyPoint *c = new MyPoint(2, 4);
 l << a << b;
```

then:

```
l.contains(c); //true
```

I tried overload `==` operator as [`doc`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlist.html#contains) says:

> This function requires the value type to have an implementation of
>   operator==().

Tried different ways but neither seems to work as expected.

Here's the code I've tried so far:

```
class MyPoint
{
public:
    int x, y;

    MyPoint(int x, int y)
        : x(x),
          y(y)
    {
    }

    bool operator == (const MyPoint &other) const
    {
        return other.x == this->x && other.y == this->y;
    }

    bool operator == (const MyPoint *other) const
    {
        return true;
    }
};

bool operator == (const MyPoint &a, const MyPoint &b)
{
    return a.x == b.x && a.y == b.y;
}
```

I tried something like:

```
bool operator == (const MyPoint *a, const MyPoint *b)
{
    return a.x == b.x && a.y == b.y;
}
```

But I read this isn't possible... I know `(*a == *c)` will be true but I'd like to it affect `contains()` behavior so that it compare using my own comparator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The operator== overloads will only work on the pointer addresses of the `MyPointer` objects, not the objects themselves.

Instead of having a list of MyPointer* objects, try making a list of MyPointer objects(i.e. `QList<MyPointer>`). You'll have to make sure that you overload the assignment operator and the copy constructor though.

If this becomes too expensive, consider converting your class to use [implicit sharing](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/implicit-sharing.html) like most of the Qt data classes do by making use of the `QSharedData` and `QSharedDataPointer` classes.